# I am trying to write a program that prints out the input string in reversed order from end to beginning

Tags: python-3.x

```
string = str(input("Please type in a string: "))
index = 0
while index < len(string):
    print(string[index])  
    index += -1
```

I am getting an error that says (string index out of range)

Answer (score 1):

strings in python are kinda like lists. You can use `print(string[::-1])` to print backwards

Edit:

To print character by character

```
string = string[::-1]
index=0
while index < len(string):
    print(string[index])
    index += 1
```

Comment: thanks for the help but what I am trying to do is print them backward and each character on a separate line. can you help me, please?

Comment: Look at edit. Or refer to @thomaoc answer

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are getting 'Index out of range' error is that your while condition will never be false since your index will almost always be less than 0.

This should fix that:

```
string = str(input())
index = len(string) - 1;  # Start at the end of your string
while index > -1:         # Until you have reached the end
    print(string[index])  
    index -= 1            # Equivalent to 'index += -1' but cleaner
```